# pywinauto: AttributeError: WindowSpecification class has no 'GetProperties' method

Tags: pywinauto

I need to validate color in Edit box.
this is my code:

```
def get_sn_edit_box_rgb(self):  
    tup = (1182, 227, 1884, 249)
    (x, y) = self.calculate_element_center_points(tup)
    (r,g,b)=self.get_pixel_colour(x, y)
```

I hard coded the rectangle coordinates of the box , but i want to get it dynamically.

I tried using 'GetProperties' and 'Rectangle' methods but received an error
" WindowSpecification class has no '---' method"

'get_properties' method some error from pywinauto inner block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it , thanks to G-d!

```
rec = self.dlg.child_window(auto_id="tSerialNumber").element_info.rectangle
```

final version will look like:

```
 def get_sn_edit_box_rgb(self):
    rec = self.dlg.child_window(auto_id="tSerialNumber").element_info.rectangle
    mid = rec.mid_point()
    (r,g,b)=self.get_pixel_colour(mid.x, mid.y)
    return (r,g,b)
```